# Прокручиваемый ExpandableListView с кнопкой

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Добрый день. Хочу сделать экран со статическим `ExpandableListView`, а под ним с небольшим отступом расположить кнопку. Проблема в том, что `ExpandableListView`занимает весь экран и кнопка как бы оказывается за пределами экрана.

Пробовал помещать 2 этих элемента в контейнер и оборачивать их `ScrollView`, но обнаружил, что адаптер отказывается заполнять `ExpandableListView` больше чем одним элементом. Погуглил и понял, что так не стоит делать.

Решил попробовать поместить кнопку в сам `ExpandableListView` как group элемент в самый конец. Теперь, прокручивая список в самый низ можно увидеть мою кнопку, однако при открытии-закрытии любого элемента кнопка пропадает и приложение падает. Тут проблема в адаптере. Мне кажется этот способ  "не очень правильный". Хотелось бы еще что-нибудь попробовать

Подскажите как правильно решить данную задачу?

Comment: Вы написали в своем вопросе "список, под ним кнопка" - разметка делает то, что вы попросили. Теперь вам надо не так. Отредактируйте свой вопрос и сформулируйте его предельно точно , чтобы было понятно, что именно вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: поместить `ListView` между двумя вьюшками - кнопкой (`button`) приткнутой к низу и к линии (`upper`) сверху

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/upper"
        android:layout_height="1dip"        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"
        android:layout_below="@id/upper"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что человеку совсем не то надо, а сформулировать внятно он это не хочет. Смотрите его коммент под моим удаленным комментарием

Comment: Я тоже не совсем понимаю, чего он хочет - написал так как я его понял - если он не хочет переформулировать или уточнить свой вопрос - это личные проблемы ТС